# getting incorrect page context path in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jboss7.x, servlet-3.0

i want to have base context path set for all jsps, irrespective of having different request path which i have in my controllers, to avoid this i have added to my below code to my
layout.jsp `<head>` section

```
 <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myapp">
```

after adding above base url line to my layout.jsp , all of my jsps have this as base url instead of request pacific relative path.

but this is working only i append my context application name to the base url for example in my local i have `http://localhost:8080/myapp`, where in the production , i will have context as  "www.myapp.com". so is there any way to avoid mentioning my context root name, that it will work dynamically with respect the environment it runs

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()

Comment: Try using <base href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}">